# pyzmq installation error

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I receive an error when trying to import `zmq`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "BasicPub.py", line 1, in <module>
    import zmq   File "/home/przemek/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from zmq import backend   File "/home/przemek/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)   File "/home/przemek/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)   File "/home/przemek/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 27, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)   File "/home/przemek/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context, ImportError: /home/przemek/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/message.so: undefined symbol: zmq_msg_gets
```

Someone has suggested that I should completely remove zmq and reinstall it.

I have tried to do it with pip but it seems that in some config files remain. I have used `locate` and I manually removed some directories. I thought that it would help but after reinstallation still I have an  error. I am using Python2.7 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Third-party package managers under Ubuntu are a Bad Idea. Contact Enthought for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libzmq*
sudo rm /usr/local/include/zmq.h
```

Since these are the two locations that ZeroMQ's libzmq installs into.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/precise/universe/p/python-zmq/uninstall/index.html) provides a few options on how to uninstall zeromq if you use a Debian operating system.

You would need to use the `purge` command:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-zmq
```

Comment: I get: "Package 'python-zmq' is not installed, so not removed. "

I uninstalled it using pip and installed again but when I tape 'pip list' this package is not listed. I don't understand...

Comment: The OP didn't use apt, but a thrid-party installer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed it using the source ditribution.
To undo this, cd to the build directory and type:

```
make uninstall
```